InterlockedCompareExchange128 is not found on newer sdk
I'm running into a problem using windows 11 sdk (10.0.22621.0) through Microsoft Visual Studio. However I'm running into a problem where it cannot find "InterlockedCompareExchange128".
The specific error message looks like:
error C3861: 'InterlockedCompareExchange128': identifier not found
It can find InterlockedCompareExchange64, but not InterlockedCompareExchange128. I've previously used windows 10 sdk (10.0.18362.0) where everything worked.

Can you share the MSVC version, your OS version and your CPU architecture?
InterlockedCompareExchange128() function only available on MSVC version 1500 or higher,and it requires a x64 CPU to run.
